# "This post has been edited since you began" - The color of "edited" should be changed

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks

When you edit a post and another person edits it before you click <kbd>Save edits</kbd>, this message shows up:

[image]

Maybe the `edited` word color should be changed? Personally, I find it hard to see, flashing with the orange color around.

I'm using dark mode, but I didn't test if it is the same in ugly mode.

Maybe just a color change from light blue to grey could be the solution.

Comment: Agree that it isn't the best choice of color from a design perspective, disagree that it is hard to see. I am kind of curious how someone who is color blind can read that though, the white on orange already seems to lack a little contrast.

Comment: I personally think that certain colors blend strangely, like `#ff0000` and `#0000ff`. And this grey also seems strange with orange next to him (sorry if I repeat strange, I'm french and I can't find the right synonym)

Comment: I agree. To me it's just a strange gray blur.

Comment: Ah, I see it from time to time - looks suspiciously like the chat color scheme, so something tells me this is a leftover from the older times. Definitely looks out of place

Comment: Been a long while since i saw that message - but wasn't "edited" a link to take you to the new edit?

Comment: Yes, so I meant maybe the color of the links in orange rectangles should be changed.

Comment: People generally associate blue with links... maybe the orange rectangle could use some recoloring.

Comment: Yeah, I think the actual problem here is the orange, not the blue.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Oh, I see, I didn't notice that the word "edited" was in the standard link color, I thought it was grey from the strange contrast. So the problem definitely comes from the orange. Maybe some greyscale could fix it?